# Using IIS instead of IIS Express to run ASP.Net core Application

Tags: asp.net-core, iis, asp.net-core-3.1, iis-express

How can use IIS  instead of IIS Express to run ASP.Net core Application ?  Is is possible to do this  and can map my application to virtual directory ?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/iis/?view=aspnetcore-5.0 Please tell us which step failed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can use IIS instead of IIS Express to run ASP.Net core Application ? Is is possible to do this and can map my application to virtual directory ?

If you'd like to deploy and host your ASP.NET Core application(s) on IIS, you can [install the .NET Core Hosting Bundle](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/iis/hosting-bundle?view=aspnetcore-5.0) on the IIS first, then [publish your app to a IIS site](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/publish-to-iis?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio) you created.

Besides, if you'd like to run and debug ASP.NET Core apps with local IIS, you can refer to following docs:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/how-to-enable-debugging-for-aspnet-applications?view=vs-2019#debug-aspnet-core-apps
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/iis/development-time-iis-support?view=aspnetcore-5.0

***Note:***

*1) please run Visual Studio as an administrator while you are debugging ASP.NET Core apps running with IIS*

*2) To make site runs as expected on **HTTP** protocol, please comment out `app.UseHttpsRedirection();` within startup class*

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    //...

    //app.UseHttpsRedirection();

    //...
```